# Get elements and count of Array of unknown type

Tags: swift, swift2

Let's say we have an Array, assigned to a variable with the type `Any`

```
let something: Any = ["one", "two", "three"]
```

Let's also assume we don't know if it's an array or something entirely else. And we also don't know what kind of `Array.Element` we are dealing with exactly.

Now we want to find out if it's an array.

```
let isArray = something is Array // compiler error
let isArray = (something as? [Any?] != nil) // does not work (array is [String] and not [Any?])
```

Is there any elegant solution to tickle the following information out of the swift type system:

1. Is the given object an Array
2. What's the count of the array
3. Give me the elements of the array

(bridging to NSArray is not a solution for me, because my array could also be of type [Any?] and contain nil-values)

Comment: The key is, at runtime it could be an array of anything. How can we cast `something` so we actually have the variable `array`?

Comment: If you already know it's an array, why don't you assign it like this `let something: [Any?] = [...]`?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez In reality I get the array from somewhere else (as one of the elements of another `[Any]` array), so the assignment above is a simplification so it's easier to explain the problem.

Comment: Do you mean that you do not know whether `something` is actually an array or not, and want to test this fact?

Comment: @dfri yes, exactly... and also get the count and the elements

Comment: A not so elegant solution that requires `Foundation` is `something as? AnyObject is NSArray`

Comment: @milos bridging to NSArray will not work if the Array contains nil (which is perfectly valid with Swift's Array)

Comment: In that case `let something: Any = [1, nil]` doesn't compile either...

Comment: @milos `let something: Any = ["one", "two", "three", nil] as [Any?]`

Comment: I did assume you got the array from somewhere else, but if you know it's an array, you can store it as an array of `Any?` instead of just storing it as a single `Any`.

Comment: @stefreak I love your last comment... Let me think...

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I get the array from somewhere else and sadly cannot store it as array of `Any?` ... :( And I don't even know if it is an array or not.

Comment: @stefreak consider `protocol P {}; extension Array : P {}; something is P`

Comment: @milos yes, that works! that is also exactly what I found too (see my answer below ...) I just can't believe it's the only solution :D

Comment: You can also use type introspection to see if `something` has a collection displaystyle, e.g. `if let disp = Mirror(reflecting: something).displayStyle where disp == .Collection { // is array }`, but I believe @milos protocol conformance check above is the ideal one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I love @stefreak's question and his solution. Bearing in mind @dfri's excellent answer about Swift's runtime introspection, however, we can simplify and generalise @stefreak's "type tagging" approach to some extent:

```
protocol AnySequenceType {
    var anyElements: [Any?] { get }
}

extension AnySequenceType where Self : SequenceType {
    var anyElements: [Any?] {
        return map{
            $0 is NilLiteralConvertible ? Mirror(reflecting: $0).children.first?.value : $0
        }
    }
}

extension Array : AnySequenceType {}
extension Set   : AnySequenceType {}
//    ... Dictionary, etc.
```

Use:

```
let things:  Any = [1, 2]
let maybies: Any = [1, nil] as [Int?]

(things  as? AnySequenceType)?.anyElements // [{Some 1}, {Some 2}]
(maybies as? AnySequenceType)?.anyElements // [{Some 1}, nil]
```

See [Swift Evolution mailing list discussion](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160229/011666.html) on the possibility of allowing protocol extensions along the lines of:

```
extension<T> Sequence where Element == T?
```

In current practice, however, the more common and somewhat anticlimactic solution would be to:

```
things as? AnyObject as? [AnyObject] // [1, 2]

// ... which at present (Swift 2.2) passes through `NSArray`, i.e. as if we:

import Foundation
things as? NSArray  // [1, 2]

// ... which is also why this fails for `mabyies`
maybies as? NSArray // nil
```

At any rate, what all this drives home for me is that once you loose type information there is no going back. Even if you reflect on the `Mirror` you still end up with a `dynamicType` which you must switch through to an expected type so you can cast the value and use it as such... all at runtime, all forever outside the compile time checks and sanity.

Comment: I personally don't think this is an issue, as the `AnyArray` protocol should not be conformed to by random structure and class types: it should only exist (and we should be able to put so much responsibility at the developer declaring it) as a type test protocol for `Array`. Hence, conforming `Dummy` to `AnyArray` above don't really, imho, cover a practical case that we would possibly run into (even if somewhat moving away from "logical error safety" and placing it in the hands of the developer... :) )

Comment: Thank you so much! :) What exactly is the problem / difference? Also your very nice three-line solution only solves the first part of my question (Is the given object an array), not part 2. and 3.

Comment: @stefreak I believe what milos points to here is the possibility of making use of the protocol `AnyProtocol` (conforming to it) for some structure/class/etc type, when we've only ever created this protocol for type checking if something is an array. If someone were to use `AnyArray` like this, it would break our type control elsewhere. So it _does_ describe a possible problem, but one that faults in a logical error by a developer. As long as you're running a one-man-project, you're most likely safe as you know yourself never to let random types conform to `AnyArray`.

Comment: Yep, nicely put @dfri. But I am also +1 stefreak's solution. Excellent both Q and A.

Comment: @milos for your last part: the conditional casting only works if you get the type EXACTLY right. so if you'd write 

    `let maybies: Any = [1, nil] as [Int?]`and
    `let things: Any = [1, 2] as [Int]`

it would stop working

Comment: @milos if you wrap up your post a little bit and/or put the Edit 2 solution to the top I am happy to accept your response ... nice solution combining reflection and the protocol solution!

Comment: @milos good stuff with the Swift Evolution mailing list discussion

Comment: @stefreak, thanks for prompting me to tidy up that answer - it really needed it!

Comment: Good job and excellent answer, thank you very much @milos and have a nice day :)

Comment: @milos I'd still add that `something as? AnyObject as? [AnyObject]` is the same as `something as? NSArray` under the hood - I think that's an interesting fact and I didn't know this before.

Comment: @stefreak: I was unsure about it since in the question you state that "bridging to NSArray is not a solution for me", but you are also right that it is a relevant fact to mention. In any case, I'm happy to put that back. Is the current version ok?

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to @milos and OP:s protocol conformance check, I'll add a method using runtime introspection of `something` (`foo` and `bar` in examples below).

```
/* returns an array if argument is an array, otherwise, nil */
func getAsCleanArray(something: Any) -> [Any]? {
    let mirr = Mirror(reflecting: something)
    var somethingAsArray : [Any] = []
    guard let disp = mirr.displayStyle where disp == .Collection else {
        return nil // not array
    }

    /* OK, is array: add element into a mutable that
     the compiler actually treats as an array */
    for (_, val) in Mirror(reflecting: something).children {
        somethingAsArray.append(val)
    }

    return somethingAsArray
}
```

Example usage:

```
/* example usage */
let foo: Any = ["one", 2, "three"]
let bar: [Any?] = ["one", 2, "three", nil, "five"]

if let foobar = getAsCleanArray(foo) {
    print("Count: \(foobar.count)\n--------")
    foobar.forEach { print($0) }
} /* Count: 3
     --------
     one
     2
     three      */

if let foobar = getAsCleanArray(bar) {
    print("Count: \(foobar.count)\n-------------")
    foobar.forEach { print($0) }
} /* Count: 5
     -------------
     Optional("one")
     Optional(2)
     Optional("three")
     nil
     Optional("five")  */
```

Comment: Still awesome and complete answer! Thank you very much for the work! :)

Comment: Awesome! Just to note that in my 2.2 playground, I need to cast in the first line: `as [Any]`

Comment: @milos Updated to a more general usage, do you still need to cast for this to work? The above works for me for all kinds of examples I can think up (even without casting), using Swift 2.2.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting: "error: contextual type 'Any' (aka 'protocol<>') cannot be used with array literal"

Comment: @milos: Sounds like you are not using exactly the same example as me above. You are not allowed to include `nil` (as an assignment by array literal) in an array assigned to a type `Any` (without some casting). Note that in my example above, however, `foo` does not contain any optionals or nil.

Comment: @dfri, I'm copy/pasting your code as-is. The line that throws the error is: `let foo: Any = ["one", 2, "three"]` on Xcode 7.3 (7D175)

Comment: @milos Weird! Works fine for me (also at 2.2). The wonders of `Any`... :)

Comment: @dfri: Yes, this was all too fast for me to process. I'll have to ponder about it again later... It also reminds me how much I need to learn *and* how fast Swift is changing...

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I came up with is the following, but I don't know if it's the most elegant one :)

```
protocol AnyOptional {
    var anyOptionalValue: Optional<Any> { get }
}
extension Optional: AnyOptional {
    var anyOptionalValue: Optional<Any> {
        return self
    }
}
protocol AnyArray {
    var count: Int { get }
    var allElementsAsOptional: [Any?] { get }
}
extension Array: AnyArray {
    var allElementsAsOptional: [Any?] {
        return self.map {
            if let optional = $0 as? AnyOptional {
                return optional.anyOptionalValue
            }
            return $0 as Any?
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can just say

```
if let array = something as? AnyArray {
    print(array.count)
    print(array.allElementsAsOptional)
}
```

Comment: Hi @stefreak. Your "type tagging" approach can be slightly simplified and generalised. I've added the variant to my answer (Edit 2) – see what you think.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on a playground:

```
// Generate fake data of random stuff
let array: [Any?] = ["one", "two", "three", nil, 1]
// Cast to Any to simulate unknown object received
let something: Any = array as Any

// Use if let to see if we can cast that object into an array
if let newArray = something as? [Any?] {
    // You now know that newArray is your received object cast as an
    // array and can get the count or the elements
} else {
    // Your object is not an array, handle however you need.
}
```

Comment: Here you've explicitly declared `array` as an array (of optional `Any`:s). The problem the OP described is the case where we _only know `something` to be captureable by type `Any`_ (i.e., can be anything), and that `something` is not necessarily an array. If we can actually declare `something` as an array in the first place, we wont have any issue here.

Comment: Hmm it will stop working if you replace the first line with `let array: [String?] = ["one", "two", "three", nil]
`

Comment: @dfri I did declare `array` as an array because `let something: Any = [...]` doesn't compile, as you can see on the answer though, `array` is only being used to be cast to an `Any` object.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez `let something: Any = ["one", "two", "three"]` compiles for me with Xcode 7.3/Swift 2.2.

Comment: @JAL Try `let array: [Any?] = ["one", "two", "three", nil, 1]`, I was trying to simulate data a little bit more random than "three strings"

Comment: @dfri we didn't declare something as type `[...]`, we declared it as `Any` (`let something: Any`), the compiler doesn't have a way to "remember" that it was casted from an array, to the compiler, it could be `Any`thing.

Comment: I did, however, try to use it with `let array: [String?] = ["one", "two", "three", nil]` as mentioned by @stefreak and it fails to cast even though `String?` should be castable to `Any?`, so I'm not sure what's with that.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez yeah! I found that to be really really strange too.

Answer (score 0):

I found that casting to `AnyObject` works for an array of objects.  Still working on a solution for value types.

```
let something: Any = ["one", "two", "three"]

if let aThing = something as? [Any] {
    print(aThing.dynamicType) // doesn't enter
}

if let aThing = something as? AnyObject {
    if let theThing = aThing as? [AnyObject] {
        print(theThing.dynamicType) // Array<AnyObject>
    }
}
```

Comment: But It seems to not work anymore when something is an array of optionals :( `let something: Any = ["one", "two", "three", nil] as [String?]`

Comment: @stefreak That's because `Any` is more "optional" than `Optional<AnyObject>`.  Not sure how I would get around that one.